# Killing all python scripts except grep process and a specific python script

Tags: centos, command-line, process

How can I run command in bash to kill all python scripts except script called `test.py` and the `grep`'s pid itself, in case we are using something like `ps -ef |grep`

I think I can use something like pgrep python to ignore the grep process, but how do I also exclude the test.py script?  I know there is an option to do `grep -v`, is there option to do `pgrep -v`

***Clarification***: except grep process- means when we do for example `ps -ef |grep test1.py`we get also the grep pid that used to bring this result.
I don't want to kill it as this process is no longer exist in the stage that results are shown.

Comment: `pgrep` and `pkill` are perhaps better solutions than the usual `ps ... | grep -v grep` or `ps ... | grep '[s]omething'` tricks.

Comment: What should happen if different `test.py` scripts are running in parallel, possibly with varying command lines (e.g., `test.py -a`, `test.py -b`, etc.)?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/797057/how-to-kill-all-python-processes-except-one-from-bash/797059#797059

Answer (score 0):

You could use something along these lines:

```
pkill $(pgrep python | grep -xv $(pgrep test.py))
```

Working from the inside out, this:

1. gathers the PID for test.py with `pgrep test.py`
2. sends that PID to `grep -xv` which will exclude it (`-v`; the `-x` option says to match the entire line (PID)) from the list gathered by:
3. `pgrep python` to gather the list of python scripts you want to kill

You may need to tweak the pgrep's to find exactly the python processes that you want, but that's the basic structure. Adjust it to your situation by working again from the inside out:

1. run `pgrep test.py` to ensure that it finds exactly the PID that you're expecting. Look into the `pgrep -f` option to match the full process name to be more sure.
2. run `pgrep python` (or similar) to find the "python scripts" that you want to kill off.
3. put it all together!

Comment: For me, `pgrep myscriptname.py` doesn't capture any of the instances of the script. I'm on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: It does not make sense to me that you once grep fpr `python` and once for the script name. How is that supposed to work? Of course, it is a general problem that scripts can be called directly and indirectly.

Comment: @HaukeLaging I approached the question of *"kill all python scripts except script called test.py"* in sequence, by finding all of the python scripts (assuming *that part* works as intended) and then filtering out the one they want to keep. Is your concern around `pgrep python` *not* finding "all python scripts"?

Answer (score 0):

A general hint for the usage of `ps` with `grep`, the usual case that you do not want the `grep` command line to be matched:

```
ps -ef | grep '[t]est'
```

Will match `test` in command lines but `test` itself does not appear in the `grep` command line.

## getting the PIDs

```
ps -eo pid,comm | awk 'NF==2 && $2~"\\.py$" && $2!="test.py" { printf "%d ",$1; }'
```

I just realized that this works for file names up to 16 characters only.